# DomainComponent error with openssl

Tags: ssl-certificate, openssl

I am creating a simple PKI to use TLS with an LDAP server.

I created the root CA request and certificate with this in the config file:

```
[ ca_dn ]
0.domainComponent       = "org"
1.domainComponent       = "example"
```

I then created the signing CA request and certificate with this in the config file:

```
[ ca_dn ]
0.domainComponent       = "org"
1.domainComponent       = "example"
```

Then I created the ldap request with this in the config file:

```
[ server_dn ]
0.domainComponent       = "org"
1.domainComponent       = "example"
2.domainComponent       = "ldap"
```

But when I want to create the certificate with

```
openssl ca -config etc/signing-ca.conf -in certs/ldap.example.org.csr -out certs/ldap.example.org.crt -extensions server_ext
```

I get this message:

```
The domainComponent field needed to be the same in the CA certificate (example) and the request (ldap)
```

I can see that the ***ldap.example.org.key*** and ***ldap.example.org.crt*** files are created, the ***.crt*** file beeing empty.
Am I misunderstanding something in this process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your OpenSSL config file will have a option called `policy` which points to a policy section. For example `policy = [policy_match]`.  A `[policy_match]` section (usually just below the option) will list which elements of the Distinguished Name are either `optional`, `supplied` or `match`. For example:

```
[policy_match]
countryName=match
organizationName=match
organizationalUnitName=optional
domainComponent=match
```

Chances are you have a `domainComponent=match` as shown in the example, which means that the request's domainComponent must be the same as that of the certificate signing the request (the CA certificate).  Change it to `optional` (it doesn't have to be present in the request) or to `supplied` (it has to be present, but it doesn't have to match).

More details are available in the [OpenSSL CA man page](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/ca.html) under *Policy Format*.